# Preventing multiple assignments of work items in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

we are using Azure DevOps as our ALM system. When a user story or bug fix is resolved, it shows in a public query - like a stack - where our QA team members subsequentially pull tickets independently for verification. As this is part of a pull request review, a PR can not be merged unless QA finished testing. So we aim for fast response times and parallelization of testing to minimise the potential of merge conflicts. Often times, we find that multiple work items are self-assigned to the same people, while other team members do not have work items assigned, increasing the potential response times for our devs (unless people change assignments) and leading to a rather subsequential then parallel verification of work items

So we are looking for a way in Azure Dev Ops that allows us to make sure that members of a certain user group can only be assigned one work item of certain work item type and state at the time. We looked into Custom Rules in detail but failed to get anything like this out of it. I'm thankful for any ideas and hints on how this can be accomplished (extensions also welcome)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such rule or policy in Azure DevOps.

And it won't prevent someone from working on it anyway to be honest... I assume testing multiple changes in a single go isn't an option? It would simplefy things tremendously...